# Redirecting ALL traffic to sub domain site to a single URL on main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying hard to find a solution for this. I want all the traffic to my sub domain (e.g. http://sub.example.com) **INCLUDING ALL URLs (posts, pages, categories, tags, etc.)** to be redirected to a single URL on my main domain (e.g. http://example.com/photos). So far, nothing has worked. Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, so posting here for those who might have the same situation as me. This works perfectly for my needs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/photos  [L,R]
```